# Android - query all Customer Orders from odata service

Tags: android, odata

I have WCF Data Service (from sample MS Northwidth database), my Android app requesting data from this service with code:

```
NorthdataService service = new NorthdataService();
Query<Customers> query = service.createCustomersQuery("/Customers");
for (Customers cust : query){
        Log.d(log_tag, "Customer Name - " + cust.getCustomerId());
    }
```

I try query customer Orders:

```
Log.d(log_tag, "Orders - " + cust.getOrders());
```

and see Orders - null

Also I know that the data on Orders can I get a request:

```
http://Server:82/northdata.svc/Customers('ALFKI')/Orders
```

I try query:

```
for (Customers cust : query){
        Log.d(log_tag, "Customer Name - " + cust.getCustomerId());
        String custName = "/Customers" + "('" + cust.getCustomerId() + "')" + "/Orders";
        try{
        Query<Customers> cquery1 = service.createCustomersQuery(custName);
        for (Customers orders : cquery1){
            Log.d(log_tag, "Orders2 - " + orders.toString());
        }
        }
        catch(Exception e){}
    }
```

I see result:

```
Orders2 - northwindmodel.Customers@40b49f68  
Orders2 - northwindmodel.Customers@40c1de10  
Orders2 - northwindmodel.Customers@40bdaea8  
Orders2 - northwindmodel.Customers@40a6d238
```

How get all OrderID from one Customer?

Answer (score 0):

The URI ~/Customers('ALFKI')/$links/Products identifies the set of products related to the Customer with Id='ALFKI'.

Comment: Yes I know how to get all OrdersID for ALFKI?

Answer (score 0):

Oh, Yes! I solved My "problem"... solution very simple, need use in FOR construction Orders Query.